# link two dataframes without a common column to form a relation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes:

df_A:

```
SrNo    Statement       
1       My name is Liam and my son is Olivia    and Noah
2       My name is Emma and my son is Oliver and Eva
3       My name is William and my son is Sophia, Elijha
4       My name is Isabella and my son is James, Charlotte, Benjamin ,Amelia
```

df_B:

```
SrNo    Statement                               Value1  Parent
1   Son of Olivia is Lucas and Mason            Olivia      
2   Son of Noah is Ethan and Evelyn             Noah 
3   Son of Oliver is Harper and Mia             Oliver
4   Son of Eva is Aria and Mila                 Eva
5   Son of Sophia is Sofia and Avery            Sophia 
6   Son of James is Logan and Jackson           James
7   Son of Charlotte is Sebastian and Jack     Charlotte
```

I need to populate the SrNo from df_A to df_B, column Parent but i do not have any common columns in those two dataframes. Also there is no same format in Statement column of df_A and df_B but the individual values will always be there.

I was trying to find the value from Value1 of df_B in Statement column of df_A so that i can relate the two dataframes, but have not been successful. Is there something i can do to achieve this?

Due to operational limitations i cannot modify df_A.

Expected output:

df_C:

```
SrNo    Statement                               Value1  Parent
1   Son of Olivia is Lucas and Mason            Olivia      1   
2   Son of Noah is Ethan and Evelyn             Noah        1
3   Son of Oliver is Harper and Mia             Oliver      2
4   Son of Eva is Aria and Mila                 Eva         2
5   Son of Sophia is Sofia and Avery            Sophia      3
6   Son of James is Logan and Jackson           James       4
7   Son of Charlotte is Sebastian and Jack     Charlotte    4
```

Comment: `Due to operational limitations i cannot modify df_A.` so can you create another dataframe based off `df_A`? also please show your efforts and expected output.

Comment: @Manakin.  I added the expected output. Also df_A is received from external source which i cannot perform any modifications. I am still trying a few more approaches, will update as soon as i complete them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a dictionary from df_A that maps different names to their associated df_A *SrNo* IDs.

The text in df_A seems to follow a pattern - all the interesting names come after the text *"and my son is"*. Additionally, the names are separated by either commas or the word *and*, so after setting up your df's:

```
import pandas as pd
df_A = pd.DataFrame( {
(1,       "My name is Liam and my son is Olivia    and Noah"),
(2 ,      "My name is Emma and my son is Oliver and Eva"),
(3 ,      "My name is William and my son is Sophia, Elijha"),
(4 ,      "My name is Isabella and my son is James, Charlotte, Benjamin ,Amelia")}, columns=["SrNo", "Statement"])
```

Ensure that the dataframe's index is set to "SrNo" that we'll use as an ID.

```
df_A.set_index("SrNo", inplace=True)
```

and then create the function that will extract the values we'll use to inform your relation:

```
import re
def extract_names(text, ignore_before):
    start=text.find(ignore_before,0)
    extract_content = text[start+len(ignore_before):].strip()
    return [n.strip() for n in re.split(r"(?:,|and)", extract_content)]
```

This creates a function that will extract the names as a list from your text patterns - it uses [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split)  to extract those names into a list, using commas and the word "and" as separators<sup>[1]</sup>. If you want to change that for alternate matches, read up on [regex](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html), or try out some examples live at this useful website [www.regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/VVr2NV/1) - tailoring the regex to select any delimiters you want to identify and split your names by. The function will ignore any text that comes before the `ignore_before` parameter.

So for example, if I call that function as follows:

```
extract_names("My name is Isabella and my son is James, Charlotte, Benjamin ,Amelia", "and my son is")
```

It returns a list of extracted names:

```
['James', 'Charlotte', 'Benjamin', 'Amelia']
```

Using that function, you can then create a lookup dictionary that translates the names extracted into their index lookup values (the value of SrNo from df_A)

```
lookup_dict = {n:k for k,v in df_A.to_dict()['Statement'].items() for n in extract_names(v, "and my son is")}
```

The contents of this would be :

```
 {'James': 4,
 'Charlotte': 4,
 'Benjamin': 4,
 'Amelia': 4,
 'Sophia': 3,
 'Elijha': 3,
 'Oliver': 2,
 'Eva': 2,
 'Olivia': 1,
 'Noah': 1}
```

I've written it here as the product of a list (dict) comprehension that loops over df_A, does the extract and maps it onto the dictionary key.

Finally, to apply this lookup dictionary to the content of df_B, you can make use of pandas' `apply` method as so:

```
df_B['Parent']=df_B['Value1'].apply(lambda x : lookup_dict.get(x))
```

This will update/overwrite the "Parent" column with the appropriate value extracted from the `lookup_dict` using whatever name is found in "Value1".

```
        Value1      Parent
        James       4
        Olivia      1
        Elijha      3
        Amelia      4
        Oliver      2
        Charlotte   4
```

Names that aren't matched will return a value of None, so keep an eye out for those.

You might encounter problems if any of your names contain the word "and"<sup>[1]</sup>, or include a comma - additionally, this makes the assumption that all the names are unique.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> Fix this by tweaking the regex used to do the splitting to `r"(?:,|\band\b)"` which forces that "and" to be a word on its own, allowing you to match names like "Ferdinand" for example.